# EntityType 'SelectListItem' has no key defined (Duplicated) - [Key] Is Present

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, selectlistitem

One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

> \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'SelectListItem'
>   has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet
>   'SelectListItems' is based on type 'SelectListItem' that has no keys
>   defined.

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Country Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public List<SelectListItem> country = new List<SelectListItem>();
        public List<SelectListItem> Country
        {
            get
            {

                country.Clear();
                using (UsersContext DB = new UsersContext())
                {
                    var cat = DB.Countries;
                    foreach (var q in cat)
                    {
                        country.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = q.Name, Value = q.Id.ToString() });
                    }
                    return country;
                }
            }
        }
```

But I have already declared `[Key]`. What I have to do else?

Comment: you can shorten your code by doing `return cat.Select( x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.ToString() }).ToList();`. No need for `country.Clear()` because you'll be replacing the reference. Where exactly are you getting this error?

Comment: Here `public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
            LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
        }` @CallumLinington

Comment: A database call in a property getter? You need to learn the basic difference between a property and a method [Choosing Between Properties and Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229054%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Simple Membership... You should use ASP.NET Identity - it's more EF friendly [link](http://www.asp.net/identity)

Comment: So basically no solution? rite?

Comment: Yeah, but Simple Membership will make your life a living hell - and it isn't worth the pain. Easier to switch it out. Plus the error your giving means you can't create the database because it doesn't exist and you haven't got a strategy in for creating it. So you haven't gone too far that you can't just switch it out.

Comment: okay if i use linq to sql? will it help?? @CallumLinington

Comment: No, thats something entirely different. Basically you're using code first, this will need to create a database. So in your context or global.asax you will have something that says `DropOrCreateDatabaseInitilizationStrategy()` or usually `*DatabaseInitializationStrategy` which creates the database needed by EF. Simple Membership doesn't work that way from what I can remember

Comment: For ASP.NET Identity implementation check out this [repo](https://bitbucket.org/no1_melman/missionfitness/overview)